# How to investigate the differences between two Docker images of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

The docker image of Ubuntu 14.04 is larger in size and has the `lsb_release` command.

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:14.04
root@c0384d45aba3:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
root@c0384d45aba3:/# exit
exit
$ docker images ubuntu:14.04
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              14.04               7c09e61e9035        6 weeks ago         188 MB
```

The docker image of Ubuntu 16.04 is smaller in size and does not have
the `lsb_release` command.

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:16.04
root@853f2dd91c36:/# lsb_release -a
bash: lsb_release: command not found
root@853f2dd91c36:/# exit
exit
$ docker images ubuntu:16.04
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              16.04               0ef2e08ed3fa        6 weeks ago         130 MB
```

Starting with their Dockerfiles, how can I get to the bottom of what causes this difference?

Comment: If your real actual problem is "what can I do about that", the solution is to insstall the package [`lsb-release`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lsb-release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the Dockerfiles for both images.

- Dockerfile for 14.04: https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/1a5cb40f41ac4829d8c301ccd2cf3b7a13687a8b/trusty/Dockerfile
- Dockerfile for 16.04: https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/1a5cb40f41ac4829d8c301ccd2cf3b7a13687a8b/xenial/Dockerfile

Here is the only difference between these two files.

```
-ADD ubuntu-trusty-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /
+ADD ubuntu-xenial-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /
```

So now we download both the .tar.gz files from

- https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/1a5cb40f41ac4829d8c301ccd2cf3b7a13687a8b/trusty/ubuntu-trusty-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
- https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/1a5cb40f41ac4829d8c301ccd2cf3b7a13687a8b/xenial/ubuntu-xenial-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz

Indeed lsb_release is contained in trusty but not in xenial.

```
$ tar -tf ubuntu-trusty-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz | grep lsb_release$
usr/bin/lsb_release
$ tar -tf ubuntu-xenial-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz | grep lsb_release$
$
```

Then we extract the contents of both tarballs to directories and we can confirm that trusty is larger than xenial.

```
$ mkdir trusty xenial
$ tar -xf ubuntu-trusty-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz -C trusty
$ tar -xf ubuntu-xenial-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz -C xenial
$ du -sh trusty xenial
208M    trusty
141M    xenial
```